# Cannot tether to Windows phone - SSID shows an asterisk

Tags: wifi-tethering, windows-mobile, wep

I have a Neuropad 2 running Android 4 ICS, and it is generally OK when using WiFi.

I want to tether it to my HP phone running Windows 6, which means I have to use the WMWiFiRouter app. Unfortunately, this app only offers WEP encryption, which doesn't bother me from a security standpoint.

The tablet picks up the SSID, and registers it when given the password, but will not connect to it. Instead, in the WiFi settings, it says "saved, secured with WEP", and when given the command to connect, does nothing.

What I find odd is that in the pad's WiFi settings, my own routers are simply identified with their SSIDs, but the one for the phone has an asterisk in parentheses immediately before it i.e. (*)HP_Phone - saved, secured with WEP

I do not know what this indicates, or why it is refusing to connect.
Any enlightenment would be appreciated.